# Icons on sidebar stretch across whole sidebar

Tags: html, css, icons, sidebar

I'm new to HTML/CSS and I came across a problem and couldn't find a solution for it. I want to have a sidebar, which I managed to do. In this sidebar are 5 icons for navigation. Now, my issue is that I want the icons to be evenly spread across the sidebar to fill it completely and not leave spaces between or underneath them. (I also want the sidebar to have even spacing on top and bottom but couldn't do that either.)
My HTML:

```css
body{
    background: #1A1A1A;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.side_bar{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1A0066, #7B1685);
    opacity: 0.7;
    height: 93%;
    width: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.side_bar a{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding:  30% 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    color: #6944DA;
}
.side_bar a:hover{
    background-color: #5A315E;
}
.active_icon{
    background-color: #6F119D;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>None</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="side_bar">
    <a class="active_icon" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope someone can help me out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox. You're making your side_bar class flex and you can use flex-direction to make them vertical (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` you can achieve this here:

```css
body{
    background: #1A1A1A;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.side_bar{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1A0066, #7B1685);
    opacity: 0.7;
    height: 93%;
    width: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.side_bar a{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    color: #6944DA;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.side_bar a:hover{
    background-color: #5A315E;
}
.active_icon{
    background-color: #6F119D;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>None</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="side_bar">
    <a class="active_icon" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

mdn:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: Hi @Hyron if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.